# Spring MappingException: Could not determine type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am building a Single-Page-Webapp for testing-scenario and i am using spring-jpa. I want to use this JSON data-model for my post-request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "test-title",
  "releaseDate": "2021/12/15",
  "rating" : {
      "stars" : 5,
      "comment" : "very exciting"
   }
}
```

If i start my application, i get the following error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: de.demo.dto.Rating, at table: books, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(rating)]

If i am declaring the class "rating" with @Entity and add the field "id", the application is starting without errors (if i am using an @OneToOne annotation). But for the class "Rating" i do not want to use an own data table with an "id". Can everyone help me with my issues? How do i fix this problem?

Class books:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Books {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String releaseDate;
    private Rating rating;
}
```

class Rating

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Rating {
    int stars;
    String comment;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution. I can use the Embedded- and Embeddable-Annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems you want one to one relationship but dont want it to be in another table, best thing comes to my mind is saving that rating as a json object String. So you might need to do cruds with some third party library like GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution. I can use the Embedded- and Embeddable-Annotation